# How can i remove GRUB from my hard drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, lubuntu

i am a first timer with Linux

I needed something lightweight so i downloaded Lubuntu 18.04, i wanted to keep my Windows 7 Starter installation so i wanted to install Lubuntu in an USB. I flashed the Lubuntu image to an USB, and then i used the Live CD version for a while, everything was great so i installed Lubuntu into another USB.

The problem is that during installation i selected my main HDD for GRUB.

Now, GRUB shows up everytime i turn on my PC, the problem is that if i unplug the usb, GRUB gives me both "no such device" and "unknown filesystem", it enters GRUB rescue mode, and doesn't let me boot Windows.

This doesn't happen if i have the USB with Lubuntu plugged in, when that USB is plugged in i can choose Lubuntu or Windows 7 and they both work perfectly fine

But i want to get rid of GRUB, i really dont like the fact that i cant boot into Windows 7 when the USB is not plugged in, i would like to get back the Windows 7 Bootloader.

Is there any way i could do this?, Could reinstalling Lubuntu and choosing the USB drive for GRUB fix the issue?

I've searched and found several ways to do this, like using easyBCD to get rid of GRUB, or using the command line in the repair function in a Windows 7 installation disk, but i don't know if it would work in my case, so i'm asking for help here

Comment: I think you can boot to the USB.  Then purge grub from that partition and install it only on the main partition.  That will let you boot Win7. You still get the grub popup. If you want to get rid or grub then YES there are lots of ways to fix this.  You can use Boot-Repair disk to fix it as well.  You can use that to remove grub from all disks and put in the standard win boot loader.

Comment: No re-install Lubuntu and selecting the thumb-drive for `grub` will just install a new grub MBR to the flash-drive, and the old one on your hdd will remain, thus nothing will change. You must boot your windows 7, and have it take ownership of the MBR. Windows 7 uses the `bootrec` command to fix this, which can be run from windows 7 recovery media, or your booted windows 7 system.  I'm not sure of your setup, but I'd for sure `grub-install` to your flash-drive anyway so you can select it using your machine's BIOS (or test it boots that way first; however that can be fixed later with a  'live').